# center-block and margin:0 auto is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have problem with this code the problem is i can't center the last block 
when it come down after resize the page 
i tried also with margin:0 auto but it;s not working with me here

the code which i tried with :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

  <div style="background:blue"class=" col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 ">

  3
  </div>
   <div style="background:black" class=" col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 ">
   2
   </div>
    <div style="background:red;" class=" center-block col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4   ">
    1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10876/)

Answer (score 0):

To center last column use xs-offset-3

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 alert-warning">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 alert-danger">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-4 col-lg-4 alert-info">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And add [col-xs-offset.css](https://gist.github.com/dylanvalade/7362739#file-bootstrap-3-xs-offset-shim-css) to support on Bootstrap 3 offsets on XS sizes
or see result on [jsFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10904/)

Comment: why this is a solution?